# Excel: Using a named range consisting of a UDF in a OFFSET function or VBA

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, named-ranges

I made a UDF which returns a range (target cell + all consecutive non-empty cells below the target cell). (See code below)

```
Public Function RETURN_NON_EMPTY_CELLS_DOWN(Target As Range)
If Target.Value = "" Then
    RETURN_NON_EMPTY_CELLS_DOWN = Target
Else
    For i = Target.Row To Rows.Count
        If Target.Worksheet.Cells(i, Target.Column).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    RETURN_NON_EMPTY_CELLS_DOWN = Range(Target, Target.Worksheet.Cells(i - 1, Target.Column))
End If
End Function
```

Next I made a Named Range 'UnitIDs' using this UDF.

```
=RETURN_NON_EMPTY_CELLS_DOWN('Project - Units'!$A$4)
```

When I use this Named Range in a cell `=UnitIDs`, Excel shows the range without problems.
However, when I use the Named Range in an OFFSET function `=OFFSET(UnitIDs,0,0,1,1)` I get a value error.

Also when I use the named range in VBA, I get the following error: 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

In both cases everything works fine when using standard functions to determine the exact same named range. The reason I want to use an UDF is that it's a much cleaner solution.

I can't find the solution to this problem or even find out why it's not working, so any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: If your function returns a range you should specify that as the return type, and also you will need `Set` when assigning it a "value". `Set RETURN_NON_EMPTY_CELLS_DOWN = Target` etc. There may be other issues.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the issue with the OFFSET function. Still get the same error in the VBA script though, so you're probably right about there being other issues ;)

Comment: How are you trying to use it?

Comment: Nevermind, I made a fault in the VBA script not related to the Named Range. The Named Range using my UDF is now also working in a VBA script. Thanks so much for your assistance!